# Confusing Directory Permissions

Tags: permissions

**Environment**

- Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Desktop

**Permissions**

```
/media/gal_db$ ls -al
drwxrwx--- 6 admin     shared_disk  4096 Aug 15 13:31 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root      root         4096 Aug 13 12:54 ..
drwx------ 3 postgres  shared_disk  4096 Aug 15 14:28 database

/media/gal_db$ members shared_disk
gal  admin  postgres
```

**Remove postgres from shared_disk to limit access to filesystem**

```
sudo deluser postgres shared_disk
```

**Try logging into database as user gal**

```
psql -U gal
    Password for user gal:
    psql: FATAL:  could not access directory "pg_tblspc/16399/PG_9.3_201306121/16401": Permission denied
```

**Re-add postgres user to shared_disk**

```
sudo adduser postgres shared_disk
```

**Try logging into database as user gal again**

```
psql -U gal
    Password for user gal:
    psql (9.3.5)
    Type "help" for help.
    gal=>
```

Success. And confusion.

**Questions**

1. Why does postgres need to be a member of shared_disk to access the database directory?
2. Isn't it enough that postgres is the owner of the database directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the “admin” user and members of the “shared_disk” group
can access the `/media/gal_db` directory. 
So, if you take “postgres” out of the “shared_disk” group,
it can’t even *get to* the `database` directory.

Comment: To generalize, you need to be able to access all the parent directories of a file/directory to access that file/directory.